# Boolean random for a tamagotchi to show if it's sick or not

Tags: java, random, boolean

I'm trying to do a tamagotchi ( a virtual pet wich you take care of) on Java, and i want to do by using a boolean random a way to show it randomly if the tamagotchi is sick or not but i don't know how to do it, i have 3 classes the cat the animal and the application.

Comment: You must take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: boolean sick = Math.random()  > 0.5; ?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Actually, java.util.Random has a nextBoolean() method build in. You dont even need that > 0.5 thing

Comment: you're right @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica

Comment: In the future, please first try to research your problem. I've found the duplicate question in seconds after searching it via a searchengine

Answer (score 0):

You could use this line:
new Random().nextInt(1); 
This line returns an Integer: 0 (false) or 1 (true).

Comment: Err, what about new Random().nextBoolean() ? So, when you really throw such a badly formatted answer at a very unclear question, at least spend a bit more effort to give good content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Tamagotchi {

    static boolean isSick;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        isSick = new Random().nextBoolean();

        System.out.println("Pet is sick: " + isSick);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as a duplicate instead of re-anwering the question.